# Expected number of events from Poisson distribution with Gamma prior

Tags: expected-value, gamma-distribution, conjugate-prior

The expected number of events for a Poisson distribution under a Gamma prior with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (with mean $\alpha/\beta$) is:

$$
\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k & \cdot P(k \mid \alpha, \beta) \\
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k & \int_0^\infty P(k \mid \lambda) p(\lambda \mid \alpha, \beta) \, d\lambda \\
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k & \int_0^\infty \paren{\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}} \paren{\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \lambda^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta \lambda}} \> d\lambda \\
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k & \> \frac{\beta^\alpha}{k! \> \Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^\infty \lambda^{k+\alpha-1} e^{-(\beta+1)\lambda} \> d\lambda \\
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k & \> \frac{\beta^\alpha}{(\beta+1)^{\alpha+k}} \frac{\Gamma(k+\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(k+1)} \\
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty & \frac{\beta^\alpha}{(\beta+1)^{\alpha+k}} \frac{\Gamma(k+\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(k)} \\
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty & \frac{\beta^\alpha}{(\beta+1)^{\alpha+k}} \frac{1}{B(\alpha, k)} \\
= \frac{\beta^\alpha}{(\beta+1)^\alpha} & \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(\beta+1)^{-k}}{B(\alpha, k)} \\
= \paren{\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}}^\alpha & \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(\beta+1)^{-k}}{B(\alpha, k)}
\end{aligned} 
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function and $B$ is the Beta function.

Is there any way to further simplify this expression?

Intuitively, I would expect it to be at or near the expected number of events for a Poission distribution with mean equal to the expected $\lambda$ from the prior,

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbb{E}_k \text{Poisson}\left(\lambda = \mathbb{E}_\lambda(\text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta))\right) \\
= {} & \> \mathbb{E}_k \text{Poisson}\left(\lambda = \alpha/\beta\right) \\
= {} & \> \alpha/\beta
\end{aligned}
$$

## Edit

I found a [description of the `Gamma-Poisson` distribution](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/Gammapoisson.pdf), which confirms my intuition that the expected value is in fact $\alpha/\beta$.

Comment: Hint: what is the posterior predictive distribution of the Poisson-Gamma model? I think you're making this a bit more difficult by cranking directly at the definition of expectation.

Comment: Try to use double expectation formula $\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \E \E (X \mid Y) = \E X$

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163236/name-of-rv-that-results-from-integrating-over-gamma-in-gamma-product-prior-on-po?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

From the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163236/name-of-rv-that-results-from-integrating-over-gamma-in-gamma-product-prior-on-po?rq=1) given by Sycorax above it was pointed out that

$$
\frac{d^k \beta^\alpha}{(d+\beta)^{k+\alpha}} \frac{\Gamma(k+\alpha)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(\alpha)} = \binom{k+\alpha-1}{\alpha-1} (1-p)^\alpha p^k
$$

is the PDF of a [Negative Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) with parameters $(\alpha,p=d/(d+\beta))$.

We can insert this halfway through the derivation in my original question (with $d = 1$) to get:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k \cdot P(k \mid \alpha, 1/(1+\beta)) = \mathbb{E}\left[k\right] = \alpha/\beta
$$

Very cool!

Comment: This answer would be more clear if you cleaned up the notation to match that of your question. For example, you don't have $d$ in the question.

Comment: edited to make more clear